# How to completely disable output scroll lock in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: user-interface, scroll, visual-studio-code

As far as I could gather, even though VS Code's Output Panel has a `Toggle Output Scroll Lock` icon in its title area

[image: Toggle Output Scroll Lock]

*it still uses* a feature called ***smart lock*** which means scrolling is enabled only if the output area is already scrolled all the way down to the bottom before the new output is generated (more on this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10486)).

I use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.CodeRunner) and ensuring output area is manually scrolled down each time I run my code to see anything is driving me nuts.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have the same problem with code runner.

Comment: I have the same problem too. The proposed answer is more or less a workaround, and after a while the problem reappear.

Comment: when that happens, just click in the output window and then press 'ctrl + end'. It will behave as before. The problem occurs when you click on the output window with your mouse. If you don't click and just scroll, the problem will not arise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No solution right now (May 2019)

I don't know if this behavior is intended or if it's a bug, but I think currently there is no real solution to entirely solve this problem.

Maybe the provided workarounds help you to better stay in control of how the output scrolling works.

## Workarounds

#### Bring focus back to current output

1. **Disable scroll lock:** [image: open lock button] (lock should now be open)
2. **Click the "Clear Output"-button:** [image: clear output button]
   (or open the context menu of the output console (right click) and
   choose "Clear Output")
3. **Remove focus:** Make sure the output console is not focused anymore
4. **Re-run the program**
   (with `Code Runner`: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

#### Avoid the problem

If you need to check some output which isn't in the current view, hover over the output window and make sure to just **scroll using your mouse wheel without clicking inside the output window**.

---

Tested with `VSCode` version `1.33.1` and `CodeRunner` version `v0.9.9`.

Comment: How is this a solution? Also this doesnt answer the question asked.

Comment: @JoaoCarlos there is currently no better solution than these workarounds. The answer is especially orientated on the `CodeRunner` problem. The OP needs a better solution than scrolling down manually after every run. With the provided workarounds they can at least speed up their manual work.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the fix for this was released in March 2020 rather silently, as the hidden setting `output.smartScroll.enabled`.

You'll need to make the following change in `settings.json`:

```
  "output.smartScroll.enabled": false
```

Found this change mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69480#issuecomment-593401640

Comment: the answer! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also, just found this setting - while not the exact fix, it could be a relief to many people. Put the following setting in your settings.json file:

```
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
```

This will clear the old output every time you run the code and display only the current output.